# how to deal with side IO operations in recursive functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I am a complete newbie in Haskell. I am wondering why this pice of code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = run theWorld presentationIO

run dom showDom = do
       event <- readCommand
       dom' <- updateDomain dom event 
       showDom dom'
       run dom' showDom
```

.. does not work and how to solve it. The error is :

```
simpleExampleTextGameV.0.2.hs:96:16: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO World’ with actual type ‘World’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: dom' <- updateDomain dom event
      In the expression:
        do event <- readCommand
           dom' <- updateDomain dom event
           showDom dom'
           run dom' showDom
      In an equation for ‘run’:
          run dom showDom
            = do event <- readCommand
                 dom' <- updateDomain dom event
                 showDom dom'
                 ....
   |
96 |        dom' <- updateDomain dom event 
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In order to reproduce it, you could launch the rest of code:
https://github.com/agutie58/landOfLispInHaskell/blob/main/simpleExampleTextGameV.0.2.hs

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `updateDomain`, as defined on [line 66](https://github.com/agutie58/landOfLispInHaskell/blob/39404d0a3608501d55370e288c147a481d87a7b6/simpleExampleTextGameV.0.2.hs#L66), returns `World`.

But the "left arrow" on [line 96](https://github.com/agutie58/landOfLispInHaskell/blob/39404d0a3608501d55370e288c147a481d87a7b6/simpleExampleTextGameV.0.2.hs#L96) requires a monadic value on the right of the arrow, in the current monad, which in your case is `IO`.

So this means that `updateDomain` should return `IO World`, not just `World`, if you want to use it on the right side of the left arrow in a `do` block.

The right solution, however, is not to make `updateDomain` return `IO World`, but rather to drop the left arrow. Instead, use `let` to bind `dom'`:

```
run dom showDom = do
  event <- readCommand
  let dom' = updateDomain dom event 
  showDom dom'
  run dom' showDom
```

Comment: Or `dom' <- updateDomain dom <$> readCommand`.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments Fyodor and also chepner, you are absolute all right, it works perfectly after that. But I do no fully understand the solution. It means that if a certain function like run that returns IO b (in this case run :: World -> (World -> IO a) -> IO b ), it means that all actions inside  should be IO something ? I assume that event <- readCommand executes this action, whereas let is different (binding function).

Comment: And let say that in another case, i was forced that a function foo had to return something as IO World. How can I force it !? something like: foo world = (putStr "") world !? It is little strange no!?

Comment: In pure functions the chain of types it is clear, but when it comes IO actions it turns little confusing to me (and more if they are in "do" statement).

Comment: I cannot answer more questions in the comments. If you have more questions, please post them as separate questions.

Comment: Thanks anyway for all, Fyodor!